# Script to delete selected 60 days old files in Linux

Tags: linux, file, directory

i have a requirement to delete 60+ days old files from our growing linux server. There are folders for every month and files are stored in it. I just want to delete files from all monthly folder EXCEPT the December folder (named as 2012_12). 
what condition should i put in the script to not find files in all the folder like '%_12' ?

Comment: Read more about the `find` command .... (notably `-prune`)

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/ -name '*_12' -prune -o -type f -mtime +59 -delete
```

Comment: Not bad! but what about the 60+ days condition?

Comment: The -mtime +59 condition finds files older than 59 days. (Oh, maybe John edited the answer to include that).

Comment: Thank you John. really appreciate your quick response.